# SET sql_log_bin=OFF equivalent in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

In MySQL I can temporarily disable binlog with

```
SET sql_log_bin=OFF
```

How can I do the same in MongoDB, to disable oplog temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done at runtime in MongoDB.

You can restart the node without its replica set configuration, as described in the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/#a-stop-one-secondary-and-restart-as-a-standalone)